# The node filled-color is blocking the node label of this graph

Tags: graphs, tikzplotlib

Background: I am using `tikzplotlib` to convert `plt` plot to `tikz`. I am applying it on a random graph network as shown below.

Consider the following tikz code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
% This file was created with tikzplotlib v0.10.1.
\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{darkgray176}{RGB}{176,176,176}
\definecolor{steelblue31120180}{RGB}{31,120,180}

\begin{axis}[
hide x axis,
hide y axis,
scaled x ticks=manual:{}{\pgfmathparse{##1}},
scaled y ticks=manual:{}{\pgfmathparse{##1}},
tick align=outside,
x grid style={darkgray176},
xmajorticks=false,
xmin=-0.56233709013339, xmax=0.562444553413885,
xtick style={color=black},
xticklabels={},
y grid style={darkgray176},
ymajorticks=false,
ymin=-1.20947471305574, ymax=1.20995008585598,
ytick style={color=black},
yticklabels={}
]
\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:0.464839534758957,0.108082528289179)
--(axis cs:-0.464732071478461,-0.108557901089417);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:0.464839534758957,0.108082528289179)
--(axis cs:0.232917848079166,-0.999524627199763);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:0.464839534758957,0.108082528289179)
--(axis cs:-0.233025311359662,1);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:0.232917848079166,-0.999524627199763)
--(axis cs:-0.464732071478461,-0.108557901089417);

\path [draw=black]
(axis cs:-0.464732071478461,-0.108557901089417)
--(axis cs:-0.233025311359662,1);

\addplot [draw=steelblue31120180, fill=steelblue31120180, mark=*, only marks,mark options={scale=3}]
table{%
x  y
0.464839534758957 0.108082528289179
0.232917848079166 -0.999524627199763
-0.464732071478461 -0.108557901089417
-0.233025311359662 1
};
\draw (axis cs:0.464839534758957,0.108082528289179) node[
  scale=1,
  text=black,
  rotate=0.0
]{0};
\draw (axis cs:0.232917848079166,-0.999524627199763) node[
  scale=1,
  text=black,
  rotate=0.0
]{1};
\draw (axis cs:-0.464732071478461,-0.108557901089417) node[
  scale=1,
  text=black,
  rotate=0.0
]{2};
\draw (axis cs:-0.233025311359662,1) node[
  scale=1,
  text=black,
  rotate=0.0
]{3};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

This should produce the following:

[image]

Instead of:

[image]

How can we make the node label appear? (in the python code I did state to make the node label appears as seen from the second figure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code which adds the content of the nodes after the drawing is complete.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}
    % This file was created with tikzplotlib v0.10.1.
    \begin{tikzpicture} [plotstyle/.style={ scale=1,text=black,rotate=0.0}] % changed <<<<<<<<<<<
        \definecolor{darkgray176}{RGB}{176,176,176}
        \definecolor{steelblue31120180}{RGB}{31,120,180}
        
        \begin{axis}[
            hide x axis,
            hide y axis,
            scaled x ticks=manual:{}{\pgfmathparse{##1}},
            scaled y ticks=manual:{}{\pgfmathparse{##1}},
            tick align=outside,
            x grid style={darkgray176},
            xmajorticks=false,
            xmin=-0.56233709013339, xmax=0.562444553413885,
            xtick style={color=black},
            xticklabels={},
            y grid style={darkgray176},
            ymajorticks=false,
            ymin=-1.20947471305574, ymax=1.20995008585598,
            ytick style={color=black},
            yticklabels={}
            ]
            \path [draw=black]
            (axis cs:0.464839534758957,0.108082528289179)
            --(axis cs:-0.464732071478461,-0.108557901089417);
            
            \path [draw=black]
            (axis cs:0.464839534758957,0.108082528289179)
            --(axis cs:0.232917848079166,-0.999524627199763);
            
            \path [draw=black]
            (axis cs:0.464839534758957,0.108082528289179)
            --(axis cs:-0.233025311359662,1);
            
            \path [draw=black]
            (axis cs:0.232917848079166,-0.999524627199763)
            --(axis cs:-0.464732071478461,-0.108557901089417);
            
            \path [draw=black]
            (axis cs:-0.464732071478461,-0.108557901089417)
            --(axis cs:-0.233025311359662,1);
            
            \addplot [draw=steelblue31120180, fill=steelblue31120180, mark=*, only marks,mark options={scale=3}]
            table{%
                x  y
                0.464839534758957 0.108082528289179
                0.232917848079166 -0.999524627199763
                -0.464732071478461 -0.108557901089417
                -0.233025311359662 1
            };
            \draw (axis cs:0.464839534758957,0.108082528289179) node(0){}; % changed <<<<<<<<<
            \draw (axis cs:0.232917848079166,-0.999524627199763) node(1){};
            \draw (axis cs:-0.464732071478461,-0.108557901089417) node(2){};
            \draw (axis cs:-0.233025311359662,1) node(3) {};
        \end{axis}
        \draw  node[plotstyle] at (0) {0} node[plotstyle] at (1) {1} node[plotstyle] at (2) {2} node[plotstyle] at (3) {3};% added <<<<
    \end{tikzpicture}
        
    \end{document}
```

[image: a]